# Converting Non Linear Numeric PHP Array Indexes to Array Values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array comprising months (keys) and values See shortened example below. It is being generated by a legacy client system so I can only manipulate what I am presented with (not ideal).

```
$cost_data= array
            (
                [9] => 1110
                [10] => 111
                [8] => 100
                [7] => 200
                [6] => 690
                [11] => 222
            )
```

Note-the non linear keys represent months of the year.

I need to change the data structure to the format below and am not having much luck after several hours of trying different approaches and searching.

```
   $cost_data = array
   (
     array("9",1110),
     array("10",111),
     array("8",100),
     array("7",200),
     array("6",690),
     array("11",222)
    );
```

Is there a simple built in function or does anyone know a neat method for achieving this transformation?

Comment: what is that you're getting? a `print_r` dump (string)? and then convert into array data type?

Comment: you spent `several hours of trying different approaches`, but don't include at least one of those different approaches? Why should we help when you don't actually show any effort other than posting?

Comment: @Ghost i am just showing the print_r output generated by the php array. Just thought it would be easier to explain that way as i cannot get the php code generating the array. So yes thats a print_r of $cost_data output from the other system

Comment: @Sean i have tried so many approaches with the methods based on array_combine, array_map, numerous foreach attempts etc and have not managed to solve the problem.. I think pasting all my attempts into the question would serve to confuse rather than help. Just figured someone would have seen this issue before and feel good about helping a novice,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my go.

```
<?php
$cost_data= [
    9 => 1110,
    10 => 111,
    8 => 100,
    7 => 200,
    6 => 690,
    11 => 222,
];

asort($cost_data);  //sort

array_walk($cost_data,function(&$v,$k){
    $v = [$k,$v];
});

print_r(array_values($cost_data));
```

Outputs ( after some cleanup):

```
array (
  0 => array(9,1110),
  1 => array(10,111),
  2 => array(8,100),
  3 => array(7,200),
  4 => array(6,690),
  5 => array(11,222)
)
```

You can test it here.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/95557489eb19e9e34c55abef71accd1219682350

If you don't care about the keys, you can skip the `array_values` which resets the numeric indexes, and save a bit on performance.  Without the `array_values` it looks like this

```
array (
  9 => array(9,1110),
  10 => array(10,111),
  8 => array(8,100),
  7 => array(7,200),
  6 => array(6,690),
  11 => array(11,222)
)
```

So, like I said you can save a tiny bit on performance by leaving it out.  I didn't measure it but I would wager it's a bit faster then array_map, as it does pass by reference.

## update

I timed both the `array_map` and mine `array_walk`.  And for 30k iterations

```
Array Walk Time: 0.045436
Array Map Time: 0.047619
```

I would say their is no significant difference between the two.

Comment: sure, I almost thought the other guy had the same one when I went to post it. But then I realized that was array_map ... lol

Comment: just an extension to that question the output gives me an array soted as followsarray
(
array(11,222 ),array(9,1110), array(10,111),
);

Comment: what would you suggest to get it into the form array
(
array(9,1110),
 array(10,111), array(11,222), ie sorted by the second level value. Thanks again

Comment: just add `asort($cost_data);` before converting it, so just above the `array_walk` it's easier to sort it when its just a `1` level array, and `a` in the `asort` means `associative` so it preserves the keys, I'll add it in my answer.  -note- sorting is `pass by reference` so there is no assignment of a return value, in other words you don't need to do this `$cost_data = asort($cost_data);`, literally you just do this `asort($cost_data);`

Comment: that does look much easier. Thank you. I should really make yours the accepted answer now. Its much much more precise.

Comment: Yeah I just did that. Hope the other guy dont mind but yours is now more correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
$cost_data = array(
    9 => 1110,
    10 => 111,
    8 => 100,
    7 => 200,
    6 => 690,
    11 => 222
);


$converted = array_map(function($k, $v) { return array($k, $v); }, array_keys($cost_data), $cost_data);
```